# Using Java 8 Streams to update collections from another collection of a different type

Tags: java, collections, java-8, java-stream

Java 8 here. I am have 2 POJOs:

```
public class User {
  private String id;
  private String moniker;
  // ... lots of other fields

  // Getters & setters down here
}

public class UserDetail {
  private String userId;
  private String moniker;
  // ... lots of other fields

  // Getters & setters down here
}
```

I'm being given a `List<User>` and a `Set<UserDetail>`. If there are any `UserDetails` in that set whose `userId` fields match any of the `User#id` values in the user list, I need to update the respective `User#moniker` with the field of the same name in the `UserDetail` set.

I have been able to do this the "old" way (pre-Java 8 Stream/Collection APIs) like so:

```
final List<User> users = userService.fetchSomehow();
final Set<UserDetail> userDetails = userDetailService.fetchSomehow();

for (UserDetail userDetail : userDetails) {
  for (User user : users) {
    if (userDetail.getUserId().equals(user.getId())) {
      user.setMoniker(userDetail.getMoniker());
    }
  }
}
```

How could I do this with the Java 8 APIs? That is, how could I loop through both collections, and for any elements with matching IDs, use the `moniker` value from the `UserDetails` to update the `moniker` value in the `Users`?

Comment: you have a `Set<UserDetail> userDetails` - I would think into the `contains` from that `Set` and not quadratic iteration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

performance wise would be better if put `userDetails` in a map

```
Map<String, String> userDetailsMap = userDetails.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(UserDetail::getUserId, UserDetail::getMoniker));

users.stream().filter(u -> userDetailsMap.containsKey(u.getId())).forEach(u -> {
        u.setMoniker(userDetailsMap.get(u.getId()));
});
```

Comment: @Eugene we can't write every piece of code for parallel processing, it wasn't even OP requirement. But please tell me what's going to happen

Comment: Thanks @Adrian (+1) your solution works, but just so I'm not "cargo culting" here, can you explain why it is better performance to first put the `userDetails` in the map? Thanks again!

Comment: How about `users.stream().forEach(u -> {
        u.setMoniker(userDetailsMap.getOrDefault(u.getId(), u.getMoniker()));
});`? Though mutating objects in streams is a bad practice I would say.

Comment: @Naman with filter we will have less objects when calling `forEach` as OP said that  "If there are any UserDetails in that set ..."

Comment: @hotmeatballsoup nested loop is O(n^2) but with hash map the loop is O(n)

Answer (score 0):

Since your userId is dependent with moniker parameter. So, I've implemented using both stream and advance for loop. You can have a glance. Your question is tricky and interesting as well.

1. Approach One

   ```
   users.stream().forEach(System.out::println);
   userdetails.stream().forEach(userdetail->{
       for(User user : users) {
           if(user.getId().equals(userdetail.getUserId())){
               user.setMoniker(userdetail.getMoniker());
           }
       }
   });
   System.out.println("********************");
   users.stream().forEach(System.out::println);
   ```
2. Approach Two

   ```
   public static List<User> users = getUserList();
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Set<UserDetail> userdetails = getUserDetails();
      users.stream().forEach(System.out::println);
      //Note: CompareUpdateList is name of my Class
      userdetails.stream().forEach(CompareUpdateList::updateUser);
      System.out.println("********************");
      users.stream().forEach(System.out::println);
   }

   public static void updateUser(UserDetail userdetail) {
      for(User user : users) {
          if(user.getId().equals(userdetail.getUserId())){
               user.setMoniker(userdetail.getMoniker());
          }
      }
   }
   ```
3. Third Approach

   ```
       public static List<User> users = getUserList();
       public static void main(String[] args) {
         Set<UserDetail> userdetails = getUserDetails();
         users.stream().forEach(System.out::println);
         //Note: CompareUpdateList is name of my Class
         userdetails.stream().forEach(CompareUpdateList::updateUser);
         System.out.println("********************");
         users.stream().forEach(System.out::println);
      }

   public static void updateUser(UserDetail userdetail) {
      users.stream().forEach(user->{
         if(user.getId().equals(userdetail.getUserId())){
             user.setMoniker(userdetail.getMoniker());
         }
      });
   }
   ```